# Is there a way to use a Javascript package in R?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to call a Javascript file in R. Inside the Java script file has a require function that calls a a Javascript package. When I try to run this in R, I am getting a ReferenceError. I am not so familiar with frontend, but I want to use Javascript to do something for me.

rFile.R

```
extendShinyjs(script = 'file/jsFile.js')
```

jsFile.js

```
var = require('some-module')
```

Error in R:

```
Error in : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: ReferenceError: require is not defined.
```

Do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: `require` is not a JS function which works in a browser. You better should provide a precise example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: have a look at the `V8` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/index.html

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I want to call one node.js module in jsFile.js. Example: I want to use this module: https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper in my jsFile.js.

Comment: You can't use this library like this. In order to use it in the browser, you have to "browserify" it with `browserify` (if this is possible).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, I think so.

Comment: Actually, I am still exploring @Pork Chop suggestion to use v8. I am still encountering errors.

Answer (score 0):

This R Package helped me to convert the npm package to "browserify" it. Thanks for all your help.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/vignettes/npm.html#what_is_v8_(not)

If you will be encountering errors like:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

You need to remove all the lines in bundle.js that uses window. Though I am still not sure of the implications of doing so. I am still working on how to call functions.

Comment: I tried to browserify this library and when I ran `ct$source("mybundle.js")` I got the error **use of const in strict mode**. Didn't you get this error? Did you set some options to `browserify`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I haven't encountered this error. I also did not do any settings in browserify.